# Configuring user properties in Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, access-rights

I am using Camel to route files from a network path using file component. But my user credentiails doesn't have read/write access rights for that path, hence I am unable to pick up files.

If I want to access the files in the path as a different user [only for that path], how can I configure that in Camel? 
And for multiple paths there are specific user credentials to be used. So my broader issue is how can I say Camel to use a particular user for accessing particular path?

Comment: I thing you can have different <from> endpoints for each file path

Comment: that's fine...but how do I configure user properties to be used ...

Answer (score 0):

I can't see that this is possible via the camel configuration options for the `file2` component to configure a different user.

Your best course of action may be to grant the 'r' rights you require to a *camel* user consistently across all the locations you want to read files from, or to create symbolic links that have the correct access rights.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow make the whole application run as a different user? Like having a properties file or any other configuration.

Comment: If you start the camel executable, or your container if you are using one, as a different user, then that user will be used by default for the file component. Alternatively you could look at using ftp, that's another option, or the answer from string05.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the jcifs component?

http://camel.apache.org/jcifs.html

```
from("smb://otheruser@myserver.example.com/sharename?password=otheruserspassword&localWorkDirectory=/tmp")
  .to("bean:foo");
```